# What is best solution (design pattern) for this situation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have some very similar functions, but one line is different in each function.

How can I avoid code duplication?

```
public class Example{

    public void f(){
       System.out.println("Start");
       OtherExample.start();
       AnotherExample.funct1(); //DIFFERENT CODE LINE
       OtherExample.end();
       System.out.println("End");
    }

    public void g(){
       System.out.println("Start");
       OtherExample.start();
       AnotherExample.funct2(); //DIFFERENT CODE LINE
       OtherExample.end();
       System.out.println("End");
    }

    public void h(){
       System.out.println("Start");
       OtherExample.start();
       AnotherExample.funct3(); //DIFFERENT CODE LINE
       OtherExample.end();
       System.out.println("End");
    }

    public void i(){
       System.out.println("Start");
       OtherExample.start();
       AnotherExample.funct4(); //DIFFERENT CODE LINE
       OtherExample.end();
       System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Could you tell me some appropriate design patterns?

Comment: I would look into the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: With an abstract parent class?

Comment: Could you give a little more context? Is this more for instrumentation, or for method decoration?

Comment: It is a general problem, I often find similar situations in my work, but I never know what is the simpliest soultion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for prior to JAVA 8 without using [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

You can refactor your code like this to make it look neater and readable :

```
public abstact class ParentClass(){

   public void start() {
      System.out.println("Start");
      OtherExample.start();         
      callMethodLetter();
      OtherExample.end();
      System.out.println("End");
   }

   public abstract void callMethodLetter();       

}
```

Then you can extend the ParentClass and implement the callMethodLetter() to call the correct method.

Comment: Unless decorating the call is the responsibility of the parent and child Classes, this breaks the SRP... In other words it works but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Please expand would like to understand what you are saying. How would it break the SRP when child would have to say which method it need / calls.

Comment: Pretty-printing is one responsibility, doing something is another one, and probably this "something" is the main responsibility of the class.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what [**Lambda Expressions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) are for:

```
public static void f(Runnable r) {
    System.out.println("Start");
    OtherExample.start();
    r.run();
    OtherExample.end();
    System.out.println("End");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(AnotherExample::funct1);
    f(AnotherExample::funct2);
    f(AnotherExample::funct3);
    f(AnotherExample::funct4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is so simple that it's hard to avoid code duplication whilst being less verbose, but presumably you have more complicated situations in mind.

You could do it like this:

```
public class Example {

    public void f() {
        (new F()).execute();
    }

    public void g() {
        (new G()).execute();
    }

    public void h() {
        (new H()).execute();
    }

    public void i() {
        (new I()).execute();
    }

    private class F extends AbstractX {
        @Override
        public void executeFunction() {
            AnotherExample.funct1();
        }
    }

    private class G extends AbstractX {
        @Override
        public void executeFunction() {
            AnotherExample.funct2();
        }
    }

    private class H extends AbstractX {
        @Override
        public void executeFunction() {
            AnotherExample.funct3();
        }
    }

    private class I extends AbstractX {
        @Override
        public void executeFunction() {
            AnotherExample.funct4();
        }
    }

    private abstract class AbstractX {
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("Start");
            OtherExample.start();
            executeFunction();
            OtherExample.end();
            System.out.println("End");
        }

        public abstract void executeFunction();
    }

}
```

Comment: Aeshang beat me to the post, but this is more detailed, so I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 1):

you can make two separate method for start and end like below -

```
public void start() {
      System.out.println("Start");
      OtherExample.start();         
   }

   public void end() {
      OtherExample.end();
      System.out.println("End");
   }
```

than call in your method call -

```
   public void f(){
           start();
           AnotherExample.funct1(); //DIFFERENT CODE LINE
           end();
        }
```

same call with other methods too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use Java 8, this is a perfect use case for [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
public class Example {

    public void f() {
        common(AnotherExample::funct1);
    }

    public void g() {
        common(AnotherExample::funct2);
    }

    public void h() {
        common(AnotherExample::funct3);
    }

    public void i() {
        common(AnotherExample::funct4);
    }

    public void common(Runnable function){
       System.out.println("Start");
       OtherExample.start();
       function.run();
       OtherExample.end();
       System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your four "examples" methods are all inside the same class. is there a reason for it ? If these are real different "examples", make it more object oriented.

First create an Example class :

```
public abstract class Example {
  public void execute();
}
```

Then have 4 different implementations of this Example class such as :

```
public class FirstExample {
  public void execute() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can then have your code have somewhere :

```
public void wrap(Example example){
   start();
   example.execute();
   end();
}
```

And call this snippet with :

```
wrap(new FirstExample());
...
wrap(new FourthExample());
```